# selecting a range of line items using beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape images off a website that has a list over 2000 images long. When I call the section of the site that links to the images, only ~1/2 of the info is displayed in the console, because too many lines are printed. I need to see the beginning info that is cut off and I'd like to display only some of the entries.  How do I show only a range (ex,from 1-10) of the 2000+ entries in the line items?

I am using this:

```
containers = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class": "image_list"})
containers[0]
```

Answer (score 2):

You have various possibilities here:

**1. Do it inside your script**

This will print first 10 containers:

```
containers = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class": "image_list"})[0:10]
for c in containers:
    print(c)
```

**2. Do it in the shell**

You can print all all your containers and filter only lines you want to see with shell commands. That way you have flexibility to change your output without editing your code again and again.

Inside your script we will print all containers:

```
containers = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class": "image_list"})
for c in containers:
    print(c)
```

In the shell:

This will print first 10 lines:

```
python name_of_my_script.py | head
```

This will print lines 5 to 10:

```
python name_of_my_script.py | sed -n '5,10p'
```

This will print last 10 lines:

```
 python name_of_my_script.py | tail
```

Look for manual pages for additional information.

Answer (score 0):

Use indexing:

```
containers = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class": "image_list"})[0:10]
```

This will make containers have the first 10 elements (so you'll print 10 elements).

Comment: Thanks for the reply but this is giving me an invalid syntax error. I've tried changing the position of the ) after [0] with no luck

Comment: `containers = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class": "image_list"}))[0:10]` he meant this it seems